# Looking for static libpcreposix.a on msys2

Tags: gcc, dll, msys2

I'm using msys2 with mingw64 on Windows. Trying to build a statically linked exe which will run outside of msys2. (I.e. build within msys2 but run outside.)

One of my dependencies is libpcreposix. Dependency setup is as follows:

```
pacman -Syu
pacman -Su
pacman -S base-devel
pacman -S msys2-devel
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-pcre
pacman -S msys2-runtime ?
```

Using `gcc` with `-lpcreposix` or `-lpcreposix.dll` I continue to get an exe requiring the two pcreposix DLLs.

A workaround is

```
set PATH=%PATH%;\msys64\mingw64\bin
nameof.exe
```

i.e. augment the outside-of-msys2 path to include the path to the DLLs. But what I really want is to make an exe file which people can simply run as is.

I notice that within the msys2 shell, I see

```
$ find / -name \*pcreposix\*
/mingw64/bin/libpcreposix-0.dll
/mingw64/lib/licpcreposix.a
/minw64/lib/libpcreposix.dll.a
....
```

i.e. there is a `.a` for `libpcreposix` but not for `libpcreposix-0`. When compile with `gcc ... -static` it finds the `libpcreposix` static library, but there is no `libpcreposix-0` static library, and when I invoke the exe outside of msys2 it says `The program can't start because libpcreposix-0.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.`

Is this a known problem? If I'm doing something wrong I don't see what it is. Why is there a static version of only one of the two libraries?

Comment: Note: also posting here https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/issues/872